# How to print a parenthesized inorder AVL tree traversal in java

Tags: java

I am trying to print my AVL tree in the following way:

> (((10) 20 (30)) 40 (50))

Where 20 is the parent of 10 & 30. 40 is the root and the parent of 20 and 50.

Here are my current methods for printing the tree.

```
public void printTree(){
    if(isEmpty()){
         System.out.println("Empty tree");
    }else{
        printTree(root);
    }
}

private void printTree(Node t){
    if(t != null){
        printTree(t.left);
        System.out.println(t.element + " ")
        printTree(t.right);
    }
}
```

The tree currently prints as follows:

> 10 20 30 40 50

Comment: Print a `(` before `printTree` and `)` after `printTree` in the 2nd method. Both of the `printTree()`s.

Comment: @All I always thought that a tree has a root. In this case, the tree has two roots or no root? I do not understand.

Comment: Observe when you encounter each node as you do an inorder traversal. Debug the code and step through it. Where to put your parenthesis outputs should become obvious to you then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rohit Jain commented, just add them in the printTree method:

```
private void printTree(Node t){
    if(t != null){
        System.out.print("(");
        printTree(t.left);
        System.out.print(t.element + " ")
        printTree(t.right);
        System.out.print(")");
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need a closing parenthesis after `t.left` and a opening parenthesis before `t.right`.